# Where is ASP.NET MVC documentation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The main page (asp.net/mvc) only seems to have a getting started guide and tutorial, plus videos, but I'm not able to find a proper documentation (classes, methods etc). Any link that can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425/mvc-learning-resources

Comment: Second @Daniel, this is quite a different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is MSDN's official documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394709.aspx

Comment: daniel where is the current documentation i.e.. MVC4 or 5

Answer (score 2):

I think using [ASP.NET MVC Source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) is much better than Reflector

Answer (score 1):

[*Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) by Steve Sanderson is the best place to start in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

I am serious. There are a lot of times when I can't make the head or tail out of ASP.NET MVC APIs, and those are the times when I use Reflector to see how they're done and what they are  doing.

Answer (score 0):

MVC documentation is very poor which is very strange for Microsoft's standards. The best and in my opinion the most complete reference is Steven Sanderson's [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865). I gave up on MSDN MVC documentation long time ago.